# What technology does the iPhone game "Zombie Highway" use?

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know anything about the technology behind the "Zombie Highway" iPhone game?

What 3D engine does it use, especially what kind of tools did they use for the UI animations, transitions, etc.?

Also, when you go to the settings screen, they are using the native iPhone keyboard and controls. Do you think that's all UIKit overlaid on top?

It looks brilliant!

Comment: -1. I think this is a bad question because most likely nobody except the creator of the game is able to answer that question. And since they might not be members of this community it's probably simpler to ask them directly...

Comment: Agreed; and for posterity's sake: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/626/is-how-was-entire-game-x-made-off-topic

Answer (score 1):

Try [contacting them](http://www.renderpazstudios.com/contact) through their website. If they are nice enough they will disclose some technical info about their projects.

Yes, usually when you need to show keyboard input or message alerts, a new UIKit layer is overlaid on top of the existing OpenGL view.